# XSLT with method="text" - include an XML element to the output

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to convert some semistructured data into a SQL command. Let's say I need to transform this XML:

```
 <Data>
     <ID>1</ID>
     <Code>Test</Code>
     <SomeData><AnythingCanBeHere /></SomeData>
 </Data>
```

into this text:

```
 INSERT SomeTable (ID, Code, SomeData)
 VALUES (1, 'Test', '<SomeData><AnythingCanBeHere /></SomeData>');
```

I have output method set to text:
     
I'm having hard time to get the SomeData element with anything in it to the ouput.

I found simmilar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584282/how-to-include-the-node-xml-in-my-xslt-text-output), but the answer suggests to set output method to XML, which is a bit weird :-) Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. There are two answers in the other question you linked to, and either one  of them will work.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: First answer sets the output method to XML, but the output is pure text. The second answer expects I know the structure of the "SomeData" element, but I don't, it can be anything.

Comment: The output of the answer that uses `XML` as the output method is not text. It's an XML fragment that may contain text nodes - even free-standing text nodes. Why do have a problem with that?

Comment: OK, I'll use it :-) But still I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve this with method set to text?

Comment: It's possible, but quite laborious and error-prone to do yourself - see the links here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733618/opposite-method-to-disable-output-escaping-in-xslt/